# Cauchy Schwartz Inequality proof about functions with defining a new inner product

Tags: linear-algebra, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow (0,+\infty)$ be a continuous function, then

$$\int _a^b f(x)dx . \int _a^b \dfrac{1}{f(x)}dx \geq (b-a)^2$$

By usual inner product $\langle f,g \rangle = \int _a^b f(x)g(x)dx$, we get the following inequality

$$\int _a^b f^2(x)dx . \int _a^b \dfrac{1}{f^2(x)}dx \geq (b-a)^2$$

How to prove the first one?

Comment: Apply the second inequality to the square root of $f$ …

Comment: Schwarz, not Schwartz.